# Trying to update Nexus 5 to 5.1.1 and using Nandroid backup

Tags: updates, nexus-5, nandroid

I'm trying to update my Nexus 5 to 5.1.1, but when I restore my Nandroid backup I lose the update.

What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

That's because you backed up the older Android version, so when you update from 5.1 to 5.1.1 you install a new version then you try to restore the backup, you will got the previous version 5.1.

You can try to restore `data` only, but i think it will crashed.

For future updates use [Titanium Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup&hl=en) to backup all of your data and then when you install the new version of Android you can restore it using the same app, Actually i always do that.

Answer (score 1):

Nandroid backup invloves backup of everything, including:

- `/system`(which is your "android version and os" in rough words, also includes the preinstalled apps)
- `/boot`(which is your kernel)
- `/data`(all apps you installed and their data (like app settings). This does Not involve your personal files)
- `/cache` (the application cache)

When you nandroid restore as whole, your system partition is overwritten. In other words, your current os (the android 5.1.1) is overwritten by the os inside nandroid backup (the older os).

Same with cache and data.

Now you can try installing just data and ignoring system to keep your os updated by choosing `advanced restore`option from recovery. This would take care of your OS reverting to older version (since we aren't restoring `/system`).

But that would mean that application data that is restored is from android 5.0 or any older version whose backup you made), but your current system is 5.1.1. Hence it will cause some incompatibility with apps and they might crash (a situation commonly referred as *FC* (short for `Force Close`) when apps crash with message `Unfortunately, [app name] has stopped working.`.

Hence it is never advised to restore anything from previous older android version's backup. Although clearing dalvic and cache might help (since then cache and app classes are created according to newer OS), but still the android's code downloaded is made for older OS (apps on play store download according to android OS you install on phone, so they have best compatibility when downloaded from store).

Hope this helps.